# Force Navigation Bar To Stay On Line

Tags: html, css, image, positioning, centering

I am trying to make a about page for my website. I am trying to center 3 images inside a div, equally spread out on the page, adjusting to the window size using css.

My question is:

*How do I get the items to be equally spaced out in the div while having the same width on the left and right sides?*

The other solutions I have read about have not actually provided me with a solution.

Here is my code:

```css
#screamer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#kinzu {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#swezii {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="managers-row">
    <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="screamer">
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="kinzu">
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="swezii">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use percentage values for your width instead of pixel ones.

```
.column {
   width: 33.333333%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0 20px;
}
```

`box-sizing` allows you to add padding to the column without making the total width greater than the target 33.333%

Answer (score 0):

Used center tag in HTML, and removed float:left;

[WORKING:DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9r5wqm/1/):UPDATED

**HTML**

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="managers-row">
    <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    <center><!-- Added -->
    <div class="one-third.column" id="screamer">
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="kinzu">
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="swezii">
    </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#screamer {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      background-image: url(http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810004.png);
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    #kinzu {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      background-image: url(http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810004.png);
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    #swezii {
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      background-image: url(http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810004.png);
      background-size: 100%;
    }

    #screamer, #kinzu, #swezii
    {
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If need be, you may want to add a fixed with to managers-row and use auto margin

```css
#managers-row {
    width: 240px;
    margin: auto;
}

#screamer {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#kinzu {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
}
#swezii {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="managers-row">
    <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="screamer">
    Screamer
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="kinzu">
    Kinzu
    </div>
    <div class="one-third.column" id="swezii">
    Swezii
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your html, as well as some incorrect css. Here is what I think you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/jkjzpz7z/2/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="managers-row">
    <h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4>
    <div class="column one-third">
        <div class="screamer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column one-third">
        <div class="kinzu"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column one-third">
        <div class="swezii"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.column {
    float: left;
}

.one-third {
    width: 33.33%;
}

#managers-row {
    width: 500px; /* Demo Only */
    text-align: center;
}

.screamer,
.kinzu,
.swezii {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000; /* Demo Only */
    background-size: 100%;
}   

.screamer {
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
}
.kinzu {
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
}
.swezii {
  background-image: url(../images/screamer.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages, and remove white space between DIV elements(really annoying)

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pm22nbkm/)

```css
.one-third-column {
    width: 33.333333333%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.one-third-column img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.one-third-column > div {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="row" id="managers-row"><h4 id="managers-head">Our Managers</h4><div class="one-third-column"><div><img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/i02.png"></div></div><div class="one-third-column"><div><img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/i02.png"></div></div><div class="one-third-column"><div><img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/1072/face_avatars/300/i02.png"></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers helped. I ended up using `margin-left:10px;` on the left aligned div, `text-align:center;` and  `display:inline-block;` to center the middle div. Lastly I used a `margin-right:10px;` to align the right div.